# In pROC, how do I get likelihood of a holdout set under smoothed ROC curves?

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

I am trying find the optimal ROC smoothing parameters using cross-validation, i.e. fitting an ROC curve to 60% of the data and then using the smoothed pdf to get the likelihood of the holdout data points. Is there a way to access the fitted functions (both the density estimate and the binormal model for TPR and FPR) in order to calculate the pdf at the holdout points? Or is there some other built-in approach?

I'm running the basic built-in example, here we can just generate a few smoothed ROCs on a training split:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)

# split into train and test
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(aSAH))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(aSAH)), size = smp_size)
train <- aSAH[train_ind, ]
test <- aSAH[-train_ind, ]

# fit ROC to train (binormal)
roc.binormal <- roc(outcome ~s100b, train, smooth=TRUE, smooth.method='binormal')

# fit ROC to train (density)
roc.density <- roc(outcome ~s100b, train, smooth=TRUE, smooth.method='density')
```

The question is, how can we evaluate the fitted positive and negative PDFs at the test points? Is it possible to access the underlying functions? I can only see the sensitivies/specificities but the thresholds are not available. Ideally there would be a function like `evaluate(roc.density, 'sen', 1.0)` which would evaluate the fitted sensitivity at that location.

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far

Comment: @Calimo I've added some context

Comment: @Calimo looking through the R code I see now that I can just reproduce the kernel part of the code to get those pdfs, so that's good. But the binormal fit doesn't give pdfs of positives and negatives - do you know any way to evaluate the likelihood of that model under some holdout points?

Comment: The thresholds disappear when you smooth. It might be feasible to get them, but pROC won't help I'm afraid, you'll need to do the smoothing yourself. As a start I'd suggest you look at the logcondens package which provides some smoothing functions, and maybe something you can use there.